# hide/show a view(image or button) on a single item click in a recyclerview list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I really need some help regarding the recyclerview list.

Suppose there is a list with 10 items, Suppose i click **one item (at position 1)**, i need make the **view(button/image) visible** on that **particular item** clicked. But when i will **click** any other **item (at position 5)** then the view(button/image)should be **visible on position 5 and not on position 1**. Can anyone tell me how can i achieve this result ? I would really appreciate if anybody help me with this. If you want some more details please do comment.

Thanks.

Comment: in your model class add one Boolean value that set to true for item that is clicked. now in your BindView method check if boolean==true then visible button

Comment: save last clicked item and hide it on next click

Comment: that is not a solution, if you scroll then all view messed up

Answer (score 0):

in recyclerview adapter when handling click listener in onBindViewHolder(Holder, Position) method you must choose the position of the view not fixed number(eg: 1,2 ,3)

ex:

=========

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final YourHolder holder, final int position) {

 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: sorry i can't add a cooment so  posting this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I've updated mi code, this is working fine!

You need to add a boolean attribute to your ItemAdapter (the item you inflate on the recyclerView).

```
public class YourItem{
    private String title;
    private String image;
    private boolean showView;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setShowView(boolean showView) {
       this.showView = showView;
    }

    public boolean mustShowView() {
       return showView;
    }

}
```

Then on your Adapter:

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    ...
    private int lastPosition;
    ...
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView title;
        private ImageView image;
        private View.OnClickListener onRowClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (lastPosition != getAdapterPosition()) {
                    Prize lastItem = getItem(lastPosition);
                    lastItem.setShowView(false);
                    adapterList.set(lastPosition, lastItem);
                    lastPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                }
                Prize item = getItem(getAdapterPosition());
                item.setShowView(!item.mustShowView());
                adapterList.set(getAdapterPosition(), item);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.prize_title);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(onRowClicked);
        }

        void bind(final Prize item) {
            title.setText(item.getTitle().toUpperCase());
            Picasso.with(context).load(item.getImage()).into(image);
            image.setVisibility(item.mustShowView() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this code is good enough to explain the way to do that:

```
    public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
      private List<Object> list;
      public myAdapter(List<Object> list){
         this.list=list;
      }
     ItemViewHolder openedRow=null; 
     @Override
     public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
            ItemViewHolder view = new ItemViewHolder(v);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            final ItemViewHolder myRowHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;

              myRowHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
   if(openedRow!=null)
   { 
      openedRow.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
        openedRow=myRowHolder;
        openedRow.image.setVisibility(View. VISIBLE);
    }
    });
    }



public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
                   image = (ImageView) 
   itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_item_main);

    }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and change these:
1-Don't set  attribute of android:visibility="visible" or "gone" in xml
2-Set this attribute in function of onBindViewHolder() in adapter():

```
holder.yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.yourBottun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!(holder.yourView.isShown() ) {
                holder.yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } 
        }
    });
```